# Excluding or overriding an AAR manifest

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, aar

I am adding a library into my project. It comes packaged as an `AAR`. But it has a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to a `BOOT_COMPLETED` starts a service. I don't want this behavior in my app. I would like it to start whenever the app starts. (This part is already done through the `AAR`, I assume in case the user force stopped the app).

Is there a way to either modify their manifest; or specify in `Gradle` not to merge their manifest (in which i'd have to declare their activities in my own manifest, I think); or to override their manifest and have a `android:enabled="false` for the `BroadcastReceiver`"?

I also would want to do it in the manifest or `Gradle`, because if I do it programmatically and if they install the app but never open it, the library service would start automatically next time the user reboots their phone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could re-declare their `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest and use `android:enabled="false"` followed by `tools:node = "replace"`.

Also if you later want to enable it, you can by using the `setComponentEnabledSetting()` method inside of `PackageManager`.

Comment: Ah nice! this seems to work, this also lead me to `tools:node:"remove"`, which is most likely what I will use. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can just open the AAR file with WinRAR or something else and edit the manifest file yourself. AARs are simply packaged ZIP files, just like APKs.

Indeed, Android Studio could handle this more gracefully, but I don't know if this is possible yet

Comment: This is a good idea especially the .aar file is not from yourself,I can have a try.